# Usage of 'à' and 'de'

Tags: prépositions, de, à

Why do you say 'mon expérience de' and not 'mon expérience à'? When do you use 'à' and when do you use 'de'?

Comment: Could you give an example? It's not clear what you mean. In the right context, you could say "*mon expérience avec des enfants*" for example, or "*mon expérience à l'étranger*".

Answer (score 3):

Quite simply because *à* is primarily (as its root sense, before it began "diluting") a locative preposition that is far more commonly found connecting two verbs than two nouns, and when connecting nouns, it's usually because the expression derives from a verbal one.

You would not write *mon expérience à* unless you specifically mean experience **acquired in a certain place** as opposed to your global experience of an object/event/place.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also still a student so this might not be the most reliable advice,
nonetheless, you're asking a good a good question, the two prepositions are often confused by most
students. They can both vary significantly based on context.

Here are some examples:

*de is normally applied in instances involving the *from* or those including *of*,

### e.g.

1. Je viens de la boulangerie (I'm coming from the bakery)
2. Lucas est un de mes amis (Lucas is a friend of mine)

Whereas à is usually used in instances involving: *to*, *at* or *in* propositions.

i.e. 
1. Je suis à la maison (I'm at home)
2. Je vais à Toulouse (I'm Going to Toulouse)
3. Je vis maintenant à Paris (I now live in Paris)

I guess the best way to understand them better is to familiarize yourself with multiple examples comparing both under
different contexts, hope this helps, all the best.